# How do I access an array in a powershell function?

Tags: powershell

I have an array of users. But when I try to access the array in a function it isn't complete.

```
$script:users = @()

Function check-user{
  foreach($user in $users){
    write-host $user
  }
}

foreach($img in $newImages){
    $users += $username
}
```

If I check $users it has 2 objects. But when I debug the code and check the function it can only see 1 of those two objects. How do I amend this so PowerShell can see both objects?

Comment: Where does `$newImages` and `$username` come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just simplified the code for the example. $newImages comes from another away and $username is a variable that is created in the last foreach

Comment: So if you have 10 items in `$newImages`, you want 10 copies of `$username` in `$users`? It's a bit unclear what _is_ supposed to happen here. Please also review [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to put together simplified examples

Comment: Yes that’s correct. When it loops in the function it only seems to be accessing the first object.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you used a [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1) `$Script:users = @()` but after that, you don't use the `$Script:` scope to reference that variable. It could happen that you would have another `$users` variable but that's unclear from your example.

What you should do is either

- be consistent about the scope modifier, i.e. use `$Script:` everywhere
- Use a parameter in your function and pass the `$users` variable to it

```
Function check-user{
  [CmdletBinding()] 
  param(
     [Parameter()]
     $Users
  )
  foreach($user in $Users){
    write-host $user
  }
}

# and use it like this
check-user -Users $users
```

If you are not comfortable with PowerShell, I think you shouldn't be using scopes. Define variables like this: `$foo = bar`.